# Slider not working in IE8 and only IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, cross-browser

For the past two weeks I have been trying to figure out why this slider isn't showing up in IE8? Can anyone shed some light on this please? http://thefoldingkayakcompany.com/

```
<!--HTML-->
    <div class="moduletable">
    <div class="moduletable_content">
    <div id="gk_is-newsimage1" class="gk_is_wrapper gk_is_wrapper-style1 clearfix">
    <div class="gk_is_preloader"><span>LOADING</span></div>
    <div class="gk_is_image" style="width:auto;height:315px;">
    <div class="gk_is_slide_group">
    <span class="gk_is_slide" style="margin-left:5px;" title="">http://thefoldingkayakcompany.com/components/com_gk3_photoslide/thumbs_big/774359slide1.png</span>
    <div class="gk_is_slide_content gk_unvisible"><div>
    <!-- The product name DIV. -->
    <a title="Edisto" href="/edisto?page=shop.product_details&amp;category_id=1&amp;flypage=flypage.tpl&amp;product_id=18" class="gk_vm_tooltip_name">Edisto</a>
    <!-- The product price DIV. -->
    <div class="gk_vm_tooltip_price">
    <span class="productPrice">&pound;1,875.00</span>
    </div>
    <!-- The add to cart DIV. -->
    <div class="gk_vm_tooltip_cart">
    <form action="http://thefoldingkayakcompany.com/index.php" method="post" name="addtocart" id="addtocart">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="shop.cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="203" />
    <input type="hidden" name="func" value="cartAdd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value="18" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="18" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="set_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="adjust_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="master_product[]" value="" />
    <input type="submit" class="addtocart_button" value="Add to Cart" title="Add to Cart" />
    </form>
    </div><span class="gk_is_pointer"></span></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gk_is_slide_group">
    <span class="gk_is_slide" style="margin-left:5px;" title="">http://thefoldingkayakcompany.com/components/com_gk3_photoslide/thumbs_big/567861slide2.png</span>
    <div class="gk_is_slide_content gk_unvisible"><div>
    <!-- The product name DIV. -->
    <a title="Citibōt" href="/virtuemart/product-page-layout?page=shop.product_details&amp;category_id=1&amp;flypage=flypage.tpl&amp;product_id=26" class="gk_vm_tooltip_name">Citibōt</a>
    <!-- The product price DIV. -->
    <div class="gk_vm_tooltip_price">
    <span class="productPrice">&pound;1,405.00</span>
    </div>
    <!-- The add to cart DIV. -->
    <div class="gk_vm_tooltip_cart">
    <form action="http://thefoldingkayakcompany.com/index.php" method="post" name="addtocart" id="addtocart">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="shop.cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="203" />
    <input type="hidden" name="func" value="cartAdd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value="26" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="26" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="set_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="adjust_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="master_product[]" value="" />
    <input type="submit" class="addtocart_button" value="Add to Cart" title="Add to Cart" />
    </form>
    </div><span class="gk_is_pointer"></span></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gk_is_slide_group">
    <span class="gk_is_slide" style="margin-left:5px;" title="">http://thefoldingkayakcompany.com/components/com_gk3_photoslide/thumbs_big/552302slide3.png</span>
    <div class="gk_is_slide_content gk_unvisible"><div>
    <!-- The product name DIV. -->
    <a title="Yukon" href="/yukon?page=shop.product_details&amp;category_id=1&amp;flypage=flypage.tpl&amp;product_id=27" class="gk_vm_tooltip_name">Yukon</a>
    <!-- The product price DIV. -->
    <div class="gk_vm_tooltip_price">
    <span class="productPrice">&pound;1,875.00      
    </span>
    </div>
    <!-- The add to cart DIV. -->
    <div class="gk_vm_tooltip_cart">
    <form action="http://thefoldingkayakcompany.com/index.php" method="post" name="addtocart" id="addtocart">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="shop.cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="203" />
    <input type="hidden" name="func" value="cartAdd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value="27" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="27" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="set_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="adjust_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="master_product[]" value="" />
    <input type="submit" class="addtocart_button" value="Add to Cart" title="Add to Cart" />
    </form>
    </div><span class="gk_is_pointer"></span></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gk_is_slide_group">         
    <span class="gk_is_slide" style="margin-left:5px;" title="">http://thefoldingkayakcompany.com/components/com_gk3_photoslide/thumbs_big/564369slide4.png</span>
    <div class="gk_is_slide_content gk_unvisible"><div>
    <!-- The product name DIV. -->
    <a title="Kodiak" href="/kodiak?page=shop.product_details&amp;category_id=1&amp;flypage=flypage.tpl&amp;product_id=30" class="gk_vm_tooltip_name">Kodiak</a>
    <!-- The product price DIV. -->
    <div class="gk_vm_tooltip_price">
    <span class="productPrice">&pound;1,992.00</span>
    </div>
    <!-- The add to cart DIV. -->
    <div class="gk_vm_tooltip_cart">
    <form action="http://thefoldingkayakcompany.com/index.php" method="post" name="addtocart" id="addtocart">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="shop.cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="203" />
    <input type="hidden" name="func" value="cartAdd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value="30" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="30" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="set_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="adjust_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="master_product[]" value="" />
    <input type="submit" class="addtocart_button" value="Add to Cart" title="Add to Cart" />
    </form>
    </div><span class="gk_is_pointer"></span></div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gk_is_slide_group">
    <span class="gk_is_slide" style="margin-left:5px;" title="">http://thefoldingkayakcompany.com/components/com_gk3_photoslide/thumbs_big/208034slide5.png</span>
    <div class="gk_is_slide_content gk_unvisible"><div>
    <!-- The product name DIV. -->
    <a title="Edisto" href="/edisto?page=shop.product_details&amp;category_id=1&amp;flypage=flypage.tpl&amp;product_id=18" class="gk_vm_tooltip_name">Edisto</a>
    <!-- The product price DIV. -->
    <div class="gk_vm_tooltip_price">
    <span class="productPrice">&pound;1,875.00</span>
    </div>
    <!-- The add to cart DIV. -->
    <div class="gk_vm_tooltip_cart">
    <form action="http://thefoldingkayakcompany.com/index.php" method="post" name="addtocart" id="addtocart">
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="shop.cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="203" />
    <input type="hidden" name="func" value="cartAdd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_id" value="18" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="18" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="set_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="adjust_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="master_product[]" value="" />
    <input type="submit" class="addtocart_button" value="Add to Cart" title="Add to Cart" />
    </form>
    </div><span class="gk_is_pointer"></span></div></div>
    </div>              
    </div>
    <div class="gk_is_pagination">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    </div>  
    <div class="gk_is_tooltip gk_unvisible"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    try {$Gavick;}catch(e){$Gavick = {};};
    $Gavick["gk_is-newsimage1"] = {
    "anim_speed": 2,
    "anim_interval": 19999,
    "autoanimation": true,
    "slide_links": true,
    "tooltip_x": 630,
    "tooltip_y": 70,
    "actual_animation": false,
    "actual_slide": 0
    };
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://thefoldingkayakcompany.com/templates/gk_mystore/js/gk_image_show.js"></script>           </div>
    </div>
    </div>

<!--CSS-->
    .moduletable .moduletable_content, .moduletable_menu .moduletable_content, .moduletable_text .moduletable_content {
    clear:both;
    padding:0;
    }

    html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display:block;
    }

    .gk_is_wrapper-style1 {
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    position:relative;
    }

    .gk_is_wrapper-style1 .gk_is_preloader {
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #F1EEE7;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:60;
    }

    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border:0 none;
    font-size:100%;
    margin:0;
    outline:0 none;
    padding:0;
    }

    .gk_is_wrapper-style1 .gk_is_image {
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    }

    .gk_is_wrapper-style1 .gk_is_slide_group {
    margin:0 auto;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    width:auto;
    }

    .gk_is_wrapper-style1 .gk_is_slide:first-child {
    margin-left:0 !important;
    }

    .gk_is_wrapper-style1 .gk_is_slide {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    }
```

Comment: What are the things that look like: `addons.css (line 48)` -- in otherwords the  `xxx (line ##)` ?

Comment: Please only post the portion of the code relevant to the question.

Comment: Also, where in the site are there sliders?

Comment: @solidariti tag this question under javaascript and jquery also , people can help out...

Comment: this is not working in ie7 also...

Comment: The slider is on the home page, I have omitted those irrelevant tags as I was using firebug to get the styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE8 is throwing error at the following place, can you fix this

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method**

```
document.body.addEvent("click", function(e){
        if(login && !login_over){
            login_fx.start(0);
            hlogin_fx.start(0);
            login = false;
            $('btn_login').removeClass("popup");
        }
        if(register && !register_over){
            register_fx.start(0);
            hregister_fx.start(0);
            register = false;
            $('btn_register').removeClass("popup");
        }
        if(cart && !cart_over){
            cart_fx.start(0);
            hcart_fx.start(0);
            cart = false;
            $('btn_cart').removeClass("popup");
        }
    });
```